# How to handle CT(Computed Tomography) grayscale binary data to RGB UIimage

Tags: ios, image, grayscale

Here is a binary CT grayscale data [down the file/date_byte1](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1q6iEmu658Rlasm8c99Z-jA)

The aim is to change the window wide window to change the CT image

The two bytes in the data are 1 pixels, and the width and height are 512 pixels

How to transform the pixel array RGB array into a bitmap

```css
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data_byte1" ofType:@""]];
    Byte *testByte = (Byte *)[data bytes];
    self.imageView.image = [self imageFromGRAYBytes:testByte imageSize:CGSizeMake(512, 512)];
}
- (UIImage *)imageFromGRAYBytes:(unsigned char *)imageBytes imageSize:(CGSize)imageSize {
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self imageRefFromGRAYBytes:imageBytes imageSize:imageSize];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return image;
}

- (CGImageRef)imageRefFromGRAYBytes:(unsigned char *)imageBytes imageSize:(CGSize)imageSize {
    
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageBytes,
                                                 imageSize.width,
                                                 imageSize.height,
                                                 16,
                                                 imageSize.width * 2,
                                                 colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    
    return imageRef;
}
```

I'm going through the following methodGet the picture
 [Obtained original diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrKOz.png) 
But I want to change the display of the picture through this method

```html
- (int)getPresentValueV:(int)v AndWidth:(int)w AndHeight:(int)h{
    
    int minv = h - roundf(w/2);
    if  (v < minv) {
        return 0;
    }
    int maxv  = h + roundf(w/2);
    if (v > maxv) {
        return 255;
    }
    int pv = roundf(255*(v - minv)/w);
    if (pv  < 0 ){
        return 0;
    }
    if( pv > 255 ){
        return 255;
    }
    return pv;
}
```

This method changes the output of PV use w h, which is less than 255, The default value of w 1600 .  The default value of h  -400.Next based on PV as an array of RGB (PV, PV, PV) to create UIimage.

```html
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < data.length/2; i++) {
        NSData *intData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i*2, 2)];

        
        [arrray addObject:@([self getPresentValueV: *(int*)([intData bytes]) AndWidth:1600 AndHeight:-400])];
    }
```

So I want to choose the different w h by the getPresentValueV method above, and get the PV to generate the RGB (PV, PV, PV) array to generate a new picture.

```html
- (UIImage *)imageWithGrayArray:(NSArray *)array {
    const int width  = 512;
    const int height = 512;
    
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    
    UInt32 * pixels = (UInt32 *)malloc(height * width * sizeof(UInt32));
    memset(pixels, 0, height * width * sizeof(UInt32));
    for (int i = 0;  i < array.count;i++ ) {
        NSArray *subArray = array[i];
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < subArray.count; j++) {
            *(pixels +i *width + j) = makeRGBAColor([subArray[j] integerValue],0, 0, 255);
        }
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels,
                                                 width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    free(pixels);
    return image;
}
```

I generated a two-dimensional array to generate a new picture, but it was not the correct result.

Comment: Post your code, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: I've changed it. Can you help me